# Java: read what keys are being pressed in other windows

Tags: java, keylogger

Is it possible to have a Java program read the keyboard buttons pressed all the time, even when I'm typing in notepad or chrome?

If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Of course it's possible - anything is. As to how; this is a Q&A site - "show me the codez" questions are frowned upon.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is directly asking for code.

Comment: google is your friend: "java keylogger" returned plenty of results.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, not actually looking for 'da codez' I just want to know how to do it, as in, what functions would I need to use or maybe a tutorial. I don't care for copy pasting code I don't understand.

Comment: @ColinD, thanks, I'm gonna look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that in plain JAVA. you would need to hook up with JNI. you need to listen to the keyboard from the OS level.

Comment: I got JNA, is there any example or tutorial I could use to listen to the keyboard?

Comment: [Google](http://google.com) has this great database of literally thousands of guides **just for what you're looking for**. Imagine that.

Comment: yeah as @Colin D mentioned this is just a keylogger.